# What is solution of $f'(f(x))=\exp(f'^{-1}(x))$ with $ f'^{-1}$ is a compositional inverse of $f'$?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, exponential-function, inverse-function-theorem

,Assume $f$ a bijective and differentiable function on its domain , I want to find solutions of this  functional  such that $f\colon\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$; $f'(f(x))=\exp(f'^{-1}(x))$ such that $f'^{-1}$ is a compositional inverse of $f'$ , I have tried $f(x)=-x$ seems works because we have $f'(f(x))$ is increasing function in the same time $f^{-1}$ exist and would be increasing imply $f'^{-1}$  exist and increasing  , if we raise exponential we have increasing functions, but am not sure about this solution ? Is there a clear solution, because its seems that it has a nontrivial solution which it is a formal power series arround $x=0 $ , we may get its coefficients using inverse function theorem ?

Comment: Should $f'^{-1}$ be the inverse of $f$ or of $f'$?  You say two different things.  Your attempt seems to suggest $f'^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f$, but the notation suggests otherwise.

Comment: Compositional inverse of f' , just a wrong typo